# Binary Search Tree within BST

Tags: c

I need to make a BST. However, each node is essentially the root for a binary search tree that can be added to that. The example is:

> You have several shoe shops stored in a BST but each shop carries different shoes

Once the shop is made, I don't understand how to use that shop root (node) and make a new tree under each shop that will hold the shoe name and a left and right pointer connecting other shoes. Would I need to make another insert function? I know I'll have to free memory, but for now I am trying to figure out the insertion of the other nodes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct mainNode {
    char* name;// Shop Name
    struct mainNode* left;
    struct mainNode* right;
    struct regNode* root; // Pointer To Sub Node
} MainTreeNode;

typedef struct regNode{
    char * name;// Shoe Name
    struct regNode *left;
    struct regNode *right;
} regNode;

MainTreeNode* insert(MainTreeNode* root, char* name);

void inOrder(MainTreeNode* root);

int main() {

    // Create tree
    MainTreeNode* MainTreeRoot = NULL;

    MainTreeRoot = insert(MainTreeRoot ,"nike");
    MainTreeRoot = insert(MainTreeRoot, "adidas");
    MainTreeRoot = insert(MainTreeRoot, "underArmour");
    MainTreeRoot = insert(MainTreeRoot, "rebbok");

    inOrder(MainTreeRoot);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}


// Inserts a new node into the tree rooted at root with data set to value.
// and returns a pointer to the root of the resulting tree.

MainTreeNode* insert(MainTreeNode* root,char* name) {

    // Inserting into an empty tree.
    if (root == NULL) {
        MainTreeNode* temp = malloc(sizeof(MainTreeNode));
        temp->name = name;
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->root = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    // Go left
    if (strcmp(name,root->name) < 0)
        root->left = insert(root->left,name);

    // Go right
    else
        root->right = insert(root->right, name);

    // Must return the root of this tree
    return root;
}

void inOrder(MainTreeNode* root){
    if (root != NULL) {
        inOrder(root->left);
        printf("%s \n", root->name);
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow...but posting code and going "I don't know what to do, just in general" isn't how it works.  Please read through the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.  Basically you have to edit down to a very specific focused question.  It may be that getting whatever you want done involves asking several of these focused questions, but the responsibility is on you to do the work of being specific and pointing to the exact roadblock or line of code that you want that question to be about.

Comment: How is the data presented?  At the moment, you have shops called `nike`, `adidas`, `underArmour` and `reebok` (except you have too many b's and not enough e's).  So, if you're presented with a `nike` shoe called `airJordan`, what are you going to do?  Yes, you need a different insert function.  What will you do if you're presented with a `target` shoe called `ePluribusUnum`?